# Delete right node of right subtree of binary search tree (C)

Tags: c, tree, binary-search-tree

I am working on a C binary search tree library and I'm trying to write a function that will delete the right node of the tree subtree. Here's the struct of my tree:

```
struct Node {
    int value;
    struct Node *left;
    struct Node *right;
};

typedef struct Node TNode;
typedef struct Node *binary_tree;
```

The tree is created like this:

```
binary_tree NewBinaryTree(int value_root) {
    binary_tree newRoot = malloc(sizeof(TNode));
    if (newRoot) {
        newRoot->value = value_root;
        newRoot->left = NULL;
        newRoot->right = NULL;
    }
    return newRoot;
}
```

Adding element to it:

```
void Insert(binary_tree *tree, int val) {
    if (*tree == NULL) {
        *tree = (binary_tree)malloc(sizeof(TNode));
        (*tree)->value = val;
        (*tree)->left = NULL;
        (*tree)->right = NULL;
    } else {
        if (val < (*tree)->value) {
            Insert(&(*tree)->left, val);
        } else {
            Insert(&(*tree)->right, val);
        }
    }
}
```

The function I wrote to delete the right node of the subtree is like this:

```
void delrightsubtree(binary_tree *tree){


        if( (*tree)->value!=NULL )

        {
                free(&(*tree)->right);
                delrightsubtree( &(*tree)->right);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("end");
        }
    }
```

However this function does not seem to work because it crash when I call this function(after adding multiple element to the tree). I don't really know how to do this.

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete node from a C binary tree without messing it up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41092850/delete-node-from-a-c-binary-tree-without-messing-it-up)

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to implement a recursive deletion method (like your insert method does).  Right now it looks like you're calling `free` on a single node, which isn't going to release any of the resources it's attached to (i.e. its children).  Instead, think about traversing the part of the tree that you want to delete and setting the appropriate values to NULL.

Comment: I am not quite sure to understand.Would you mind taking for example my Insert method and changing it for what you mean? thank you

Comment: You've got the right idea with `Insert`: to insert a node, tell your child to insert it until we reach the bottom of the tree.  Same for `Delete`: to delete a branch, tell your children to delete their children until you reach the bottom of the tree.

Comment: I edited my post with the function that I edited,it does compile but crash when I call the function

Answer (score 0):

You'll simply call recursive delete method until you reach the end (there is no next point) then you just free everything you need and set to NULL things that suppose to be set to null.